# Project fails to link with libcurl static libraries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libcurl, static-linking

I am attempting to compile the sample program supplied with the Win32 version of the libcurl static libraries using Visual Studio 2010.

So far, I have managed to resolve many compiler issues simply by including ws2_32.lib to the additional dependencies list.

Unfortunately, MSVC failed to resolve the following external symbols:

```
__imp__ldap_value_free_len referenced in function _Curl_ldap        [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_unbind_s referenced in function _Curl_ldap              [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_simple_bind_s referenced in function _Curl_ldap         [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_set_option referenced in function _Curl_ldap            [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_search_s referenced in function _Curl_ldap              [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_next_entry referenced in function _Curl_ldap            [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_next_attribute referenced in function _Curl_ldap        [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_msgfree referenced in function _Curl_ldap               [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_memfree referenced in function _Curl_ldap               [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_init referenced in function _Curl_ldap                  [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_get_values_len referenced in function _Curl_ldap        [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_get_dn referenced in function _Curl_ldap                [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_first_entry referenced in function _Curl_ldap           [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
__imp__ldap_first_attribute referenced in function _Curl_ldap       [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
symbol __imp__ldap_err2string referenced in function _Curl_ldap     [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
external symbol __imp__ber_free referenced in function _Curl_ldap   [Project Path]\libcurl.lib(ldap.obj)
```

Have I forgotten to include another static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function point to a missing LDAP library.

If you can compile curl yourself you can use the CURL_DISABLE_LDAP and CURL_DISABLE_LDAPS options to build without LDAP support.

Otherwise I think you have to link to the WinLDAP library.

Comment: it worked, with a few warnings from the linker. Should I ignore them?

Comment: The program crashed: "Unhandled exception at 0x77c0e3be in facebook-id.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x04bcd21a.", which displayed line 51 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\free.c